# Find the mathematical expectation of the given process?

Tags: statistics, expectation

$$E[\cos(2\pi t+\theta)\sin(2\pi f(t+\tau)+\theta)]$$ where $$f=a+b\cos(\alpha)$$ and $\alpha$ is uniformly distributed on the interval (0,$\pi$). $a$ and $b$ are constants 
 My approach:
$$=\cos(2\pi t+\theta)E[\sin(2\pi f(t+\tau)+\theta)]$$
$$=\cos(2\pi t+\theta)E[\sin(2\pi (a+b\cos(\alpha))(t+\tau)+\theta)]$$
$$=\cos(2\pi t+\theta)E[\sin(2\pi a(t+\tau)+2\pi b\cos(\alpha)(t+\tau)+\theta)]$$
$$=\cos(2\pi t+\theta)\int\limits_{0}^{\pi} \sin(2\pi a(t+\tau)+2\pi b\cos(\alpha)(t+\tau)+\theta)\frac{1}{\pi}d\alpha$$
$$\bigg/ 2\pi a(t+\tau)+2\pi b\cos(\alpha)(t+\tau)+\theta=x /d \bigg/$$
$$\bigg/d\alpha=-\frac{dx}{2\pi b\sin(\alpha)}\bigg/$$
$$=\cos(2\pi t+\theta)\frac{1}{2\pi^2 b\sin(\alpha)}\Big[\cos( 2\pi a(t+\tau)- 2\pi b(t+\tau)+\theta)-\cos( 2\pi a(t+\tau)+ 2\pi b(t+\tau)+\theta)\Big]$$ after applying:
$$\cos x-\cos y = -2\sin\frac{x+y}{2}\sin\frac{x-y}{2}$$ I get:
$$=\frac{\sin(2\pi a(t+\tau)+\theta)\sin(2\pi b(t+\tau))}{\pi^2b \sin(\alpha)}$$

Am I wrong or is this correct? For me the solution looks a little bit long and I was expecting a simpler solution. Maybe there are some properties I have overseen. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: How can there be an $\alpha$ in the answer?

Comment: $\alpha$ come in front of the integral after substitution with $dx$

Comment: You can't integrate over $\alpha$ and still have it in the answer. I think your integration is wrong. I get something involving Bessel functions.

Comment: Could you give me some hints?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the integral part of your 4th line.

$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi} \sin(2\pi a(t+\tau)+2\pi b\cos(\alpha)(t+\tau)+\theta)d\alpha$
$=\int\limits_{0}^{\pi} \sin(A + B cos(\alpha))d\alpha$
$=\pi \sin(A)J_0(B)$

With $J_0$ being a Bessel function of the first kind. I cheated and used Wolfram alpha to do the integral, but it is pretty much in the standard form for such an integral.
So putting it all together.

$E[\cos(2\pi t+\theta)\sin(2\pi f(t+\tau)+\theta)]=
\cos(2\pi t+\theta)\sin(2\pi a(t+\tau)+\theta)J_0(2\pi b(t+\tau))$

Comment: Thank you for your help.